# Python nested loop with condition

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements

```
my_list = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]]
my_var = 7
```

My goal is to be able to see if `my_var` is larger than all of the positions at `my_list[0][1]` and `my_list[1][1]` and `my_list[2][1]` and so on.

`my_list` can vary in length and `my_var` can also vary so I am thinking a loop is the best bet?

*very new to python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
all(variable > element for element in list)
```

or for element `i` of lists within a list

```
all(variable > sublist[i] for sublist in list)
```

This has the advantage of kicking out early if any of the elements is too large.  This works because the `... for ... in list` is an instance of Python's powerful and multifarious [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator-expression).  They are similar to [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) but only *generate* values as needed.

`all` itself just checks to see if all of the values in the [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) it's passed are true.  Generator expressions, list comprehensions, lists, tuples, and other sorts of sequences are all iterables.

So the first statement ends up being equivalent to calling a function like

```
def all_are_greater_than_value(list, value):
    for element in list:
        if element <= value:
            return False
    return True
```

with `all_are_greater_than_value(list, variable)`...

or simply

```
all_greater = True
for element in list:
    if element <= value:
        all_greater = False
        break
```

However, the generator expression is generally preferred, being more concise and "idiomatic".

Comment: It's a great example of Python's ability to read like English.

Comment: this may make you cringe but would you mind showing me how this could be done using a primitive for loop?

Comment: @Dtour: I added some for-loop examples for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this also:

```
my_list = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]]
my_var = 7
print all(all(x < my_var for x in sublist) for sublist in my_list)
```